# How can I get the value of an HTML variable and store it inside a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of code here. This is pretty much a textfield in HTML that gets the value typed in and stores it in the id called "inpKeyword."

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="Keyword" size="25" id="inpKeyword"/> <!-- enter search term -->
```

I need to have that value stored in a javascript var variable. Can someone please help me? I've been stuck on this problem for the past couple hours. Thanks in advanced!

Btw, this is all in a JSP page.

Comment: To work between server code and javascript code is to set a hidden field from the server side and then read it from the client side

Comment: He doesn't state he needs in the server code at all as I assume he knows how to do a post. Just doesn't know how to access it from js. When do you need it? On a button click/when the input loses focus?

Comment: @putvande : That is so not the way to help the people who has very little knowledge of the subject... It'l be good if u do not insult anyone.. The whole point of SO is to improve each others knowledge right?..

Comment: Yes you are right, but this is still basic and OP could have found a way to do it. This kind of questions has been answered a million times.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
var val = document.getElementById('inpKeyword').value;
```

Comment: var val = $("#inpKeyword").val(); Incase he is using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use jQuery:

```
var value = $('#inpKeyword').val();
```